# Automatically backup JailBreak iPhone DCIM photo directory

Tags: iphone, ios, launchd

Hi I heard that you can write cron job into plist and put it to JB iPhone /Library/LaunchDaemons folder in plist format

I would like to backup the photo folder every 300 seconds, so I put a com.backup.plist like this into /Library/LaunchDaemons folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>

    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.backup</string>

    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/bin/cp</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>-u</string>
        <string>/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/*.*</string>
        <string>/private/var/backup</string>
    </array>

    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>

</dict>
</plist>
```

I have created a folder of /private/var/backup with access right of 777 mobile:mobile

I rebooted the iPhone, however, the script just doesn't work

Does the failure refer to the "cp" command access right?
or should I change the /private/var/backup folder access right to something else?

btw I'm running iOS 4.3.3 Jailbreak iPhone 4

Many thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

I've not used launchd on an iPhone, but on Mac OS X, the first string to ProgramArguments needs to be the program name itself. Try changing that section from:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>-u</string>
    <string>/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/*.*</string>
    <string>/private/var/backup</string>
</array>
```

To:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>cp</string>
    <string>-u</string>
    <string>/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/*.*</string>
    <string>/private/var/backup</string>
</array>
```